Interpolation in local variable name Ruby
I've got
banana_charge_1_bananas_sold = 0
banana_charge_2_bananas_sold = 0
banana_charge_3_bananas_sold = 0
banana_charge_4_bananas_sold = 0
banana_charge_5_bananas_sold = 0

and
sale_ticket.banana_charge

which is an integer 1 to 5.
Is there any way to interpolate sale_ticket.banana_charge into the local variable name, instead of going
  if sale_ticket.banana_charge == 1
    banana_charge_1_bananas_sold += number_of_scanned_bananas
  elsif sale_ticket.banana_charge == 2
    banana_charge_2_bananas_sold += number_of_scanned_bananas
  etc.

like
banana_charge_&^{sale_ticket.banana_charge}_bananas_sold += number_of_scanned_bananas


Have you considered using an Array for this?

You could use Binding#local_variable_get e.g. binding.local_variable_get("banana_charge_#{sale_ticket.banana_charge}_bananas_sold") but you really should consider rethinking your design in this case

Trust me, I'm no developer. Much appreciated, ty

Numbered variables can be a code smell. If you see the need to iterate them, or to treat the number as data, they definitely are.


Is there any way to interpolate sale_ticket.banana_charge into the local variable name, instead of going

Technically yes using meta-programming.
# frozen_string_literal: true
# pseudo-code

number_of_bananas = 5

number_of_bananas.times do |i|
  define_method "banana_charge_#{i + 1}_bananas_sold" do
    local_variable_get("banana_charge_#{i + 1}_bananas_sold")
  end

  define_method "banana_charge_#{i + 1}_bananas_sold=" do |number_sold|
    local_variable_set("banana_charge_#{i + 1}_bananas_sold", number_sold)
  end
end

banana_charge_1_bananas_sold = 10
banana_charge_2_bananas_sold = 10
banana_charge_3_bananas_sold = 10
banana_charge_4_bananas_sold = 10
banana_charge_5_bananas_sold = 10

puts banana_charge_1_bananas_sold

This however, is very poor design, as there is a data type that exists that is designed for this purpose.
Using an Array, and based on what I think that you're trying to accomplish:
# frozen_string_literal: true
# pseudo-code

number_of_bananas_sold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
number_of_bananas_sold[4] #=> 5

number_of_bananas_sold[sale_ticket.banana_charge] += number_of_scanned_bananas


You mean start at number_of_bananas_sold = [0,0,0,0,0] , and use sale_ticket.banana_charge for the array placement when adding the number_of_scanned_bananas. Checking..

Note that arrays are 0-based whereas the OP's numbers are 1-based. You have to either adjust the index or – maybe better – use a hash with a default value of 0.

BTW, the upper (meta-programming) part in your example code is never used. You set 5 local variables and print one of them.

I think using array is a simple and great solution

worked great, thank you (the array solution)
